# quantreg package: predict.rq does only accept a single tau

Tags: r, predict, confidence-interval, quantreg

I am using `quantreg` package to calculate quantile regressions. I am fitting regressions for a number of taus and would like to calculate predicted values and 95% confidence intervals.
The problem is that the function `predict.qr` seems not to allow for more than one quantile if you add confidence limits. So far, I solved the problem using loops but that makes my code terribly long.
Minimal example:

1) one quantile (0.5) works fine

```
# prediction data set
pred.df <- data.frame(disp = 150:160) 

fit <- rq(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars, tau = 0.5)

predict.rq(fit, 
           newdata = pred.df, 
           interval = "confidence")
```

2) more than one quantile and only predicted values (no ci) also works fine

```
fit <- rq(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars, tau = c(0.5, 0.6))
predict.rq(fit, 
           newdata = pred.df)
```

3) when more than one quantile (0.5, 0.75) and ci, it does not work any more

```
fit <- rq(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars, tau = c(0.5, 0.6))

predict.rq(fit, 
           newdata = pred.df, 
           interval = "confidence")
```

Therefore my question:
is it possible to get predicted values and confidence intervals for more than one quantile regression using only predict.rq and avoid loops?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `lapply()`, which is a loop, but it is quick to implement:

```
lapply(c(0.5, 0.6), function(tau) {

fit <- rq(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars, tau = tau)

predict.rq(fit, 
           newdata = pred.df, 
           interval = "confidence")
})
```

Alternatively, you can create a wrapper function for your code and then use `Vectorize()` to have a vectorized version of such a function wrt the `tau` argument, so to use that function in the future without the need of implementing a loop.